# Spring MVC i18n validation error messages

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, internationalization

I'm getting hopeless I'm trying configure the validation error messages to come from a message source.

I have a `SignupForm.java` class as:

```
public class SignupForm {

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 32)
    private String username;

    ...
}
```

The messages are located in: `src/main/resources/i18n`:

```
-- message_en.properties
-- message_zh.properties
-- validation_en.properties
-- validation_zh.properties
```

Inside `validation_en.properties` I have:

```
org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message = Default message, can not be empty 
NotEmpty.username        = Username cannot be blank.
Size.SignupForm.username = Username must be between {2} and {1} characters long.
```

`MessageSource` configuration:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:i18n/messages</value>
            <value>classpath:i18n/validation</value>
        </list>
   </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

`Validator` configuration:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator"/> 

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
</bean>
```

As you see in the properties file I have several options and none of them is picked up when execute the validation.

[image: validation form]

Do you have any suggestions to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I had i18n resolver bean's locale set to `cn`. Changing it to `zh` solved the problem. The trouble was that it would default without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `SignupForm` in `Size.SignupForm.username` is value of `ModelAttribute` in your `Controller` (`@ModelAttribute("SignupForm"`).